# form not rendering in my custom template inside custom module

Tags: drupal-8

i want to render my form in a twig template that overrides `html.html.twig`
the twig template is named `html--resume--myform.html.twig`

inside my form class i have this code

```
public function buildForm(array $form,FormStateInterface $form_state) 
{
    $form['#theme'] = ['html__resume__myform'];   
    $form['candidate_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Candidate Name:'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Save2'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
    );
    return $form
}
```

and inside my resume.module file i have this custom template

```
function resume_theme() {
    return ['html__resume__myform' => ['render element' => 'form']];
}
```

but my form is not rendered in `html--resume--myform.html.twig`
or my $form variable is not passed to `html--resume--myform.html.twig`
`html--resume--myform.html.twig` is inside templates folder